# Get name of variable corresponding to maximum value in a list

Tags: python, list, max

I have this code:

```
timeLS1 = 0.1
timeLS2 = 0.2
timeLS3 = 0.15
timeLS4 = 0.5
timeLS5 = 0.4
timeLS6 = 0.3
timeLSv = (timeLS1, timeLS2, timeLS3, timeLS4, timeLS5, timeLS6)
timeLS = max(timeLSv)
print timeLS
index_max = timeLSv.index(timeLS)
print index_max
```

I'd like to get the maximum (`timeLS`) plus the name of the variable (`timeLS1, ...., timeLS6`) that corresponds to the maximum.

What's the easiest way to do this (instead of doing if loops after getting `index_max`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best approach, but looks good:

```
timeLS1 = 0.1
timeLS2 = 0.2
timeLS3 = 0.15
timeLS4 = 0.5
timeLS5 = 0.4
timeLS6 = 0.3

data = {key: value for key, value in locals().iteritems() if 'timeLS' in key}

key, value = max(data.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print key, value  # prints 'timeLS4 0.5'
```

You might want to avoid to create additional `data` dictionary also.

Hope that helps.